# Select specific String using Xpath and XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I want to select String between `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Input :

```
<p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl1&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
<p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl2&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
<p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl3&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
```

I want to select `p:endnote_bl1,p:endnote_bl2, etc..` from the text. It means whatever text between `&lt;` and `&gt;`. How can I write the XPath for this.

Comment: Your starting tag is `<p>` but your closing tag is `</tps:p>`.

Comment: @JackFleeting really sorry I edit code again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT, using xpath, you can simply select all `p` elements (or `tps:p` elements, if you do have namespaces), and use `substring-before` and `substring-after` to extract the text, although do note this assumes one occurrence of each of `&lt;` and `&gt;`

```
<xsl:for-each select="//p[@type='Endnote Text']">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;'), '&gt;')" />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZX7

If you could use XSLT 2.0, you could do it without the `xsl:for-each`...

```
<xsl:value-of select="//p[@type='Endnote Text']/substring-before(substring-after(., '&lt;'), '&gt;')" separator="&#10;" />
```

Or you could also use `replace` in XSLT 2.0....

```
<xsl:value-of select="//p[@type='Endnote Text']/replace(., '&lt;(.+)&gt;.*', '$1')" separator="&#10;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use just xpath, if we fix your xml like so:

```
<doc>
  <p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl1&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
  <p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl2&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
  <p type="Endnote Text">&lt;p:endnote_bl3&gt;This is a bullet list in an endnote</p>
</doc>
```

Then this expression,

```
doc/p/substring(./text(),2,13)
```

will select

```
p:endnote_bl1
p:endnote_bl2
p:endnote_bl3
```